# Assistance requested on Roblox studio

Tags: roblox

Basically I need a Roblox script and when you touch a certain thing another thing appears, plays a audio and then kicks you after the audio. But the problem is I don't know how to do it so that's why I'm asking for assistance

Comment: You are not giving enough information, what would you like to do, where is the sound located, when do you want the code to execute?

Comment: Have you looked for tutorials on [playing sounds](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/sounds-and-music)? For [detecting when parts get touched](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/events)? For [kicking players](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Player/Kick)? What have you tried? Please update your question with a code sample of what you have tried, and what isn't working.